# Virtual Box - Can I boot from host's disk to another system, safely?

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, boot, virtualbox, grub

I have windows and ubuntu (using grub of course) on my machine.

Let's say I've booted to windows and created a virtual machine on Virtualbox that boots from my own physical HDD, the same one that contains the system I'm working on. and when it boots I choose ubuntu, how dangerous is that?

what if I choose to boot from some iso to install another Linux or something? it's okay to lose grub or windows boot. it's easily repairable.

are there any other dangers? like on the stability of windows or hardware?

Comment: Why not just install one of the two OSs to a virtual disk? The one you use least often, or experiment with the most (snapshots are great here).

Answer (score 0):

It all boils down to where the boot records point to in the host and guest systems. File reading, locking, and permissions could mangle your installation on the host hdd but I don't think you'll create the Frankenstein operating system you're trying to make.

Comment: What things could be mangled That way? Other than boot record i mean.